# Why does Pyrebase4 give me a installation error when using python3.9 on macOS

Tags: pip, python-3.9

I am using pip 3.9/python 3.9 because pyrebase4 doesn't work with python 3.10.5/pip3
Here's the error:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 177, in emit
    self.console.print(renderable, overflow="ignore", crop=False, style=style)

...

"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 179, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
Message: '[present-rich] %s'
Arguments: (UpgradePrompt(old='22.1.2', new='22.2'),)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The version of pip you are using is outdated. Run the following to get rid of the error.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Thank you, I just noticed I never needed to change versions of pip and python because Pyrebase doesn’t work with cloud firestore

Comment: Did the solution work in this scenario?

Comment: Yes, it did work, and  I also noticed Pyrebase4 doesn’t support Cloud Firestore. So I have changed from cloud firestore to the realtime database.

Comment: Oh my god, thanks so much! There were like thousands of topics and answers, nothing help but this one... Thanks man!

Comment: thanks bro, i'm actually not a man, surprise!